# Xamarin.iOS custom renderer calling SetNativeControl has a very slow performance

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've built a custom renderer to get a TableView on iOS that is using the `InsetGrouped` TableViewStyle from iOS. It works fine using the following custom control & renderer:

```
public class InsetGroupedTableView : TableView
{
    public Action ForceUpdateView;
}

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(InsetGroupedTableView), typeof(InsetGroupedTableViewRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class InsetGroupedTableViewRenderer : TableViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TableView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
                return;
            var formsTableView = Element as InsetGroupedTableViewRenderer;
            var groupTable = new UITableView(Control.Frame, UITableViewStyle.InsetGrouped);
            groupTable.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(-10, 0, 0, 0);
            groupTable.Layer.CornerRadius = 20;
            groupTable.Source = Control.Source;
            SetNativeControl(groupTable);
            formsTableView.ForceUpdateView += ForceUpdate;
        }

        private void ForceUpdate()
        {
            var groupTable = new UITableView(Control.Frame, UITableViewStyle.InsetGrouped);
            groupTable.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(-10, 0, 0, 0);
            groupTable.Layer.CornerRadius = 20;
            groupTable.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            groupTable.Source = Control.Source;
            SetNativeControl(groupTable);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        }
    }
}
```

However i have some tables in my App where i'm generating `TableSection`s on the fly. As I'm replacing the Table in the custom renderer with a new control, obviously Xamarin.Forms cannot update my Tables anymore. However I just used a delegate to call the same code above again whenever I'm updating the table.

Is there any problem with this? Because the performance of it is horrible. It takes about 1.5 seconds to load the additional tables. I used some stopwatches to see if the code above is executed slow but it's really fast, just after the code above is called it takes really long to display the new Section.

Does anyone have a clue if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Does the tablviewcell have heavy UI to render?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT around 5-10 view cells with mostly Labels and Pickers. If i have the table without my renderer the generated sections appear immediately.

Comment: Can you please share more code in custom renderer?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT i edited my question and put in the full code of my renderer & custom control. In my shared code I'm just calling `ForceUpdateView()`

Comment: Why you need to call SetNativeControl in ForceUpdateView again. It looks like it is always setting the NativeControl.

Comment: You are right @JackHua-MSFT. Calling this method again was totally useless and that is also why it was so slow. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and i will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetNativeControl` should only be called once in the custom renderer.

Calling this method again was totally useless and that is also why it was so slow.